# How to get file from server using laravel and process it to react frontend

Tags: reactjs, xml, laravel, axios

I am developing system where by i am using react as frontend and laravel as my backend.I have this challenge i want to check files with certain extension lets say .txt after certain time(may be after 5min),then after checking those files if found one or more that one process it in react end using axios.How can i achieve it? I have succussed to to check my files after every 5min

Here are codes for getting files from directory  and process in react js

```
public function getFile(){
        try{
         if(File::exists('document/incoming/incoming.xml')){
            $files=File::allFiles('document/incoming');
            foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
                return response()->json(['message' => $files],200);
            }
           
            
           

         }else{
            return response()->json(['message' => 'File not  exist'],404);
         }

        }catch ( \Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['message' => 'error'],500);
        }

        
    }
```